# How to combine paths in the Spring.Net config to use it as property or constructor argument?

Tags: .net, ioc-container, spring.net

Is there an easy "built-in-way" of combining paths for using them as a single parameter?

I use an own Implementation called SpringPathCombiner to do the following:

```
<property name="CombinedPath">
  <object type="SpringExt.SpringPathCombiner, SpringExt">
    <constructor-arg name="path1">
      <object factory-method="GetBasePath" factory-object="MyConfig" />
    </constructor-arg>
    <constructor-arg name="path2" value="Temp" />
  </object>
</property>
```

This will set the Combined path to the combination of the return value of the
method GetBasePath together with "Temp", e.g. C:\MyBasePath\Temp.

The SpringPathCombiner class itself is very simple:

```
public class SpringPathCombiner
{
    private readonly string path;

    public SpringPathCombiner(string path1, string path2)
    {
        path = Path.Combine(path1, path2);
    }

    public static implicit operator string(SpringPathCombiner combiner)
    {
        return combiner.path;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return path;
    }
}
```

But I don't want to have code duplication and I think there must by a way to do this kind of job with the things brought by Spring itself. Anyone knows a way how to do this without an own implementation, e.g. using Path.Combine directly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried using an expression? For example:

```
<object id="MyObject" type="q8892913.MyClass, q8892913">
  <property name="Path" expression="T(System.IO.Path).Combine('c:\dev', 'Temp')" />
</object>
```

You can easily use properties of other objects too:

```
<object id="MyObject" type="q8892913.MyClass, q8892913">
  <property name="Path" expression="T(System.IO.Path).Combine(@(MyConfig).Path, 'Temp')" />
</object>

<object id="MyConfig" type="q8892913.MyClass, q8892913">
  <property name="Path" value="c:\dev" />
</object>
```

Comment: Thx, this does the trick. But I think, there should be a more readable option to configure this (at least with base types like strings).

Comment: Well, for conatenating strings, you can use the + [operator](http://www.springframework.net/doc-latest/reference/html/expressions.html#expressions-math), as in expression="'con' + 'cat'".

Comment: Good point, but for this case (paths) I prefer Path.Combine because I might have no control wheter the variable ends with trailing '\' or not.